# how to create an EnumMap object with key and value both as Enum?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, collections, enums

```
enum Month{JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, ...
}

enum Week{MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, ...
}
```

`Map<Month, String> monthMap = new EnumMap<>(Month.class);`  Simple EnumMap can be created like this where key is Enum and value is String

However, I want to create the EnumMap where key and value both are of enum type.

`Map<Month, Week> monthWeekMap = new EnumMap<>`  ....
what will be the syntax for creating the above enum map objet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is no different:

```
Map<Month, Week> monthWeekMap = new EnumMap<>(Month.class);
```

The [`EnumMap` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Class)) only needs the [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) of the key type, in order to decide how to allocate the array used for the actual storage (an `EnumMap` is effectively just a strongly-typed array, whose length is the number of elements in the enum: this is obtained by reflection); the value type is essentially irrelevant, because it's just storing [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) values internally.